# How can i prevent router to rout request to the failed server?

Tags: iis-7.5, arr

I'm working with IIS and ARR and the load balancing is working good ,but when a server fail the ARR still rout requests to this failed server.
How can i prevent router to pass request to the failed server without using NLB ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up **Health Test** for your farm.

See Step 2 - Configure health check monitoring:

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-(arr)/http-load-balancing-using-application-request-routing

Comment: I already have seen your answer but i didn't try it yet but when i used Server variable hash algorithm it's working with out do any thing,on the contrary,the other algorithms didn't work,if could i ask you a favor,i would ask you if do you know how Server variable hash algorithm,Request hash and Query string hash are working in a littel details,thanks.